# PHP/jQuery not updating in DB only in text-input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my form users can change the value using the Javascript below.  But when they click X2 Bet, it doesn't update the bet in the PHP..  For example, if I put 1, it works.  If I click X2, it SHOWS 2, but inserts 1 in the database.

Thanks.

```
<form action="./php/bet_process.php" method="POST" class="form betForm">
    <center>
        Balance: <span class="balance"></span> | Total Bets: <span
            class="total"></span> | Total Profit: <span class="profit"></span>
    </center>
    <hr />
    <span id="betResult"></span>
    <p class="field">
        <input type="text" id="bet" class="large" placeholder="Amount"
            name="bet" style="width: 250px;"> <span>
            <button id="x2bet">X2 Bet</button>
        </span>

    </p>
    <p class="field">
        <input id="chance" name="chance" class="large" type="text"
            placeholder="Chance" value="49.5">
    </p>
    <p class="field">
        <input id="pay" name="payout" class="large" type="text"
            placeholder="Payout">
    </p>
    <p class="field">
        <input id="profit" name="profit" class="large" type="text"
            placeholder="Profit">
    </p>
    <p class="field">
        <input type="submit" value="Bet" class="large" style="width: 360px;"
            id="betBtn">
    </p>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#x2bet').click(function () {
    $('#bet').val(parseFloat($('#bet').val()) * 2);
});


$(document).ready(function(){

  function updateValues() {
    // Grab all the value just incase they're needed.
    var chance = $('#chance').val();
    var bet = $('#bet').val();
    var pay = $('#pay').val();
    var profit = $('#profit').val();

    // Calculate the new payout.
    pay = (100-1)/chance;


    // Calculate the new profit.
    profit = bet*pay-bet;

    // Set the new input values.
    $('#chance').val(chance);
    $('#bet').val(bet);
    $('#pay').val(pay);
    $('#profit').val(profit);
  }


  $('#chance').keyup(updateValues);
  $('#bet').keyup(updateValues);
  $('#pay').keyup(updateValues);
  $('#profit').keyup(updateValues);


});
```

PHP Code:

```
    <?php
include_once('db.php');
session_start();

echo '
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="./plugins/loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
';

$updated_amount_loss = $_POST['bet'];
$updated_amount_win = $_POST['profit'];

    $selectBalance = $db->prepare("SELECT `balance` FROM `users` WHERE `uid` = :uid");

        $selectBalance->execute(array(':uid' => $_SESSION['uid']));

            $balanceRow = $selectBalance->fetch();

                $userBalance = $balanceRow['balance'];

                    if(isset($_POST['bet'], $_POST['chance'], $_POST['payout'], $_POST['profit']) &&
                        $userBalance >= 0 &&
                        $_POST['bet'] >= 0 &&
                        $_POST['bet'] <= $userBalance &&
                        strlen($_SESSION['client']) == 6) {

                            if($_SESSION['roll'] < $_POST['chance']) {

                                    echo '<p class="message valid">You won!  You rolled a ' . $_SESSION['roll'] . ' out of 100.<span class="close">X</span></p>';

                                        $result = 'Win';

                                            if($_POST['bet'] > 0) {

                                                $updateBalanceWin = $db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `balance` = `balance` + :balance WHERE `uid` = :uid");
                                                    $updateBalanceWin->execute(array(':uid' => $_SESSION['uid'], ':balance' => $updated_amount_win));
                                                $insertBetWin = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `bets`(`uid`, `result`, `amount`, `multiplier`, `time`, `roll`, `actual_amount`) 
                                                                                      VALUES (:uid, :result, :amount, :multiplier, :time, :roll, :actual_amount)");
                                                    $insertBetWin->execute(array(

                                                        ':uid'              => $_SESSION['uid'],
                                                        ':result'           => $result,
                                                        ':amount'           => $_POST['bet'],
                                                        ':multiplier'       => $_POST['payout'],
                                                        ':time'             => date("F j, Y, g:i a"),
                                                        ':roll'             => $_SESSION['roll'],
                                                        ':actual_amount'    => $updated_amount_win

                                                        ));

                                    }

                            }

                            else {

                                    echo '<p class="message invalid">You lost! You rolled a ' . $_SESSION['roll'] . ' out of 100.<span class="close">X</span></p>';

                                        $result = 'Loss';

                                            if($_POST['bet'] > 0) {

                                                $updateBalanceLoss = $db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `balance` = `balance` - :balance WHERE `uid` = :uid");
                                                    $updateBalanceLoss->execute(array(':uid' => $_SESSION['uid'], ':balance' => $updated_amount_loss));
                                                $insertBetLoss = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `bets`(`uid`, `result`, `amount`, `multiplier`, `time`, `roll`, `actual_amount`) 
                                                                                      VALUES (:uid, :result, :amount, :multiplier, :time, :roll, :actual_amount)");
                                                    $insertBetLoss->execute(array(

                                                        ':uid'          => $_SESSION['uid'],
                                                        ':result'       => $result,
                                                        ':amount'       => $_POST['bet'],
                                                        ':multiplier'   => $_POST['payout'],
                                                        ':time'         => date("F j, Y, g:i a"),
                                                        ':roll'         => $_SESSION['roll'],
                                                        ':actual_amount'    => $updated_amount_loss

                                                        ));

                                    }


                            }

                        $_SESSION['roll'] = rand(0, 10000)/100;
                        $_SESSION['client'] = rand(100000, 999999);
                        $secret = 123;
                        $_SESSION['server'] = hash('sha512', $_SESSION['roll'] . $_SESSION['client'] . $secret);

                    }


?>
```

Comment: eww, `onlclick`. bind in JavaScript and don't use attributes. Keep HTML and JavaScript separated.

Comment: Try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/sghTQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't put your jQuery inside your HTML like this. It's really hard to read and might trip up some poor programmer that needs to maintain this code.

What you'll want to do is call a different function that will update the value:

```
<button onclick="someFunc()">X2 Bet</button>
```

Then *in your JavaScript code* (that means within the `<script>` tags, you'll embed the actual function

```
function someFunc(){
    var theValue = $('#bet').val(); 
    // convert the value into a number
    var theNumber = parseInt( theValue );
    $('#bet').val( theValue * 2 );
}
```

---

Even better, don't use the `onclick` method at all! Give your button an `id` attribute and attach a click handler:

```
<button id="x2bet">X2 Bet</button>
```

```
// this is exactly the same as "$(document).ready(function(..."
$(function(){
    $("#x2bet").on('click', function(){
        var theValue = $('#bet').val(); 
        // convert the value into a number
        var theNumber = parseInt( theValue );
        $('#bet').val( theValue * 2 );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `parseInt` and a setter method in your `onclick` method. Currently, you are only getting the value of the text box and multiplying it. You need to put it back into the text box, like this :

```
 $('#bet').val(multipliedValue);
```

You're full `onclick` will look like this :

```
 <button id="changeBet" onclick="$('#bet').val(parseInt($('#bet').val())*2);">X2 Bet</button>
```

But, `onclick` is bad in many ways :

1. so ugly to see in DOM.
2. There is no seperation of concerns between HTML and JS
3. You need to add it to every single HTML tag
4. More than one statement inside it will make the DOM look unreadable(to some) etc.

Instead of this, why not use jQuery?

```
$("#changeBet").click(function() {       
   $('#bet').val(parseInt($('#bet').val())*2);
});
```

You can also use plain ol' JS :

```
var button = document.getElementById("changeBet");
button.onclick = function () {
    var input = document.getElementById("bet")
    input.value *= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you tried something there

```
<button onClick="$('#bet').val()*2;">X2 Bet</button>
```

But it's not doing what you want because in that line, you are not assigning any new value to the input with id `bet`. This should do the trick:

```
<button onClick="$('#bet').val(parseInt($('#bet').val()) * 2);">X2 Bet</button>
```

When you use the [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) function for assignment you have to pass the new value as a parameter.

I would also suggest separating the JavaScript from the HTML,

```
<button id="x2bet">X2 Bet</button>
```

And in the JavaScript

```
$('#x2bet').click(function () {
    $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val()) * 2);
});
```

Comment: This works however when the form is submitted it doesn't update the value.  Updated OP.

Comment: Do you mean, `$_POST['bet']` isn't multiplied by 2 like it's supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

isn't `$('#bet').val($('#bet').val()*2);` enough? nothing happens on your code because you are not assigning the new value back to the #bet object.. so you should change your code to this..

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you need `type="button"` otherwise buttons submit the form by default, having said that you can use `<button type="button" onClick="$('#bet').val($('#bet').val()*2);">X2 Bet</button>`. 
The best practise is though to call a function for it.

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rq9zk/)**